# How to add custom button in sales order view in admin after cancel button

Tags: admin, magento2.4, custom-button, sales-order-view

I have added custom button in sales order view on admin .But I need the custom button next to cancel button.

Answer (score 0):

**Step.1 Add di.xml in your module**

> /public_html/staging2/app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="AddButtonInOrder" type="MagePsycho\Customshipping\Plugin\Adminhtml\AddButtonInOrder" />
     </type>
</config>
```

**Step.2 Add AddButtonInOrder.php**

> /public_html/staging2/app/code/MagePsycho/Customshipping/Plugin/Adminhtml/AddButtonInOrder.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2018 Codealist. All rights reserved.
 *
 * @category Class
 * @package  Codealist_OrderViewButton
 * @author   Codealist <info@codealist.com>
 * @license  See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 * @link     https://www.codealist.com/
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Adminhtml;


class AddButtonInOrder
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
     */
    public function beforePushButtons(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar\Interceptor $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
    )
    {
        if ($context->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_view') {
            
            $order_id = $context->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
                $url = $context->getUrl('sales/*/email', ['pickup_ready'=> 'pickup_ready']);
                $buttonList->add(
                    'pickupReady',
                    ['label' => __('Pickup Ready'), 'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm(\'' . __(
                        'Are you sure you want to send a "Ready for Collection" email to customer?'
                    ) . '\', \'' . $url . '\')', 'class' => 'reset'],
                    -1

                );
            
        }
    }
}
```

upvote and accept solution if helps you :)

Comment: Please donot ask to  update or accept your answer...... Ask to  accept the answer like forcing user accept answer

Comment: Some user dont know thats why I am just added here that line..and I am not forcing..I added if help you then accept answer.